# Why am I not able to call an item in the group site as an external user?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to call https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/figg.sharepoint.com,72857af7-ba97-4f23-afd6-d62962997a39,cff6bc06-4fe1-4013-83d9-12b1394e06a6/lists/85a346a3-e7dd-463e-9eae-aad6cb36de30/items/3af557a2-98d2-4f23-8993-996c6ee00097

to get the list item info. I am doing this call via an external user which is a member of the Office 365 Group which the list item belongs to. I get a 401 response code and I believe this is a bug since the external user is a group member.

Comment: What scopes are you requesting for this user?

Comment: The same as for an internal group member where it works:)